# Primefaces tabview active index is not working correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I've changed my code completely. But active index is still showing problems. Sometimes it gets called and sometimes it doesn't.
What's wrong with the following xhtml code?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
    <h:head>
        <title>Admin Panel</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
                background-color: #eedae3;
            }
            .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
                height: 30px;
                background-color: #e74f54;
            } 
            .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{
                background-color: #6f97df;
                height: 35px;
            }
            .datatable{
                background-color: #eedae3;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>  
        <p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{profileInfoManagedBean.myCurrentTab}" >
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.tabIsChangedKana}" />


            <p:tab id="locationInfoTab" title="Location Info">

                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:growl showDetail="true" />

                    <p:panel header="New Country">  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputLabel for="country"  value="Country: "></h:outputLabel>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:inputText id="country" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.country.country}" required="true" label="City">

                                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20" />
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg1"></p:ajax>
                                </p:inputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:message id="msg1" for="country" display="icon"></p:message>
                            </p:column>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.addCountry}" value="Save" ajax="true" ></p:commandButton>
                    </p:panel>

                </h:form>
                <p:separator />

                <h:form id="countryDataTableForm">
                    <p:panel>
                        <p:growl id="messagesww" />
                        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete the selected row ?"
                                         header="Deleting Row" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation1">
                            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update="messagesww" oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()"
                                             action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deleteObject}" />
                            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" />
                        </p:confirmDialog>

                        <p:dataTable style="width: 700px;" var="coun" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.countryList}" selection="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deletingObj}" rowKey="#{coun.countryId}"
                                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                     paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25" editable="true">
                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this"
                                    listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.onEditRow}" />


                            <p:column headerText="Country">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{coun.country}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{coun.country}" style="width:100%" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column id="inactive" filterBy="#{coun.isActive}"   
                                      headerText="isActive" footerText="exact" 
                                      filterOptions="#{profileInfoManagedBean.isActiveDropDown}"
                                      filterMatchMode="exact">

                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{coun.isActive}"></h:outputText>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{coun.isActive}" >  
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />  
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" /> 
                                        </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Edit">
                                <p:rowEditor />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Delete">

                                <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" 
                                                 id="delCountry" title="Delete Country" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column selectionMode="single">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="select" />
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:panel>

                </h:form>

            </p:tab>






            <p:tab id="basicInfoTab" title="Basic info">
                <p:accordionPanel id="aPanel1">
                    <p:tab id="tab2" title="basic   info">
                        <h:form id="dkk">
                            This is basic info tab.
                        </h:form>
                        <h:form id="ddkk">
                            This is basic info tab.
                        </h:form>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </p:tab>



        </p:tabView>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'm using primefaces 3.2, JSF 2.1, Tomcat 7, netbeans 7.1, Hibernate3

---

**Update**: @rags 
i was having some problem in activeindex.
After the activeindex and everything started working, i started to compare my code to know what was going wrong.
Now, when i changed the required="false" to required="true" in the input fields and other components, the activeindex won't work again.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
    <h:head>
        <title>Admin Panel</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function deleteObj(x){
                //alert("checking javascript - " + x);
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
                background-color: #eedae3;
            }
            .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
                height: 30px;
                background-color: #e74f54;
            } 
            .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{
                background-color: #6f97df;
                height: 35px;
            }
            .datatable{
                background-color: #eedae3;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>  
        <h:form id="mainForm">

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

            <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete the selected row ?"
                             header="Deleting Row" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation1">


                <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update=":mainForm:growl mainForm:myTabViewID:aPanel:countryTable" oncomplete="confirmation1.hide()"
                                 action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deleteObject}">
                    <!--                                        <f:ajax render=":mainForm" />-->
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" type="button" />
            </p:confirmDialog>

            <p:tabView id="myTabViewID" activeIndex="#{profileInfoManagedBean.myCurrentTab}" >
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.tabIsChanged}" />


                <p:tab id="locationInfoTab" title="Location Info">

                    <p:accordionPanel id="aPanel" activeIndex="#{profileInfoManagedBean.myCurrentATab}"> 
                        <p:tab id="tab1" title="Country">

                            <p:outputPanel>  
                                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:outputLabel for="country"  value="Country: "></h:outputLabel>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:inputText id="country" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.country.country}" required="false" label="Country">
                                            <p:watermark value="Enter a country name" for="country" />
                                            <f:validateLength for="country" minimum="5" maximum="20" />
                                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg1" />
                                            <f:validateRequired for="country" />
                                        </p:inputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:message id="msg1" for="country" display="icon"></p:message>
                                    </p:column>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.addCountry}" update=":mainForm" style="margin:10px 0" id="btnAdd"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>

                            <p:separator />
                            <p:outputPanel id="countryTable">

                                <p:dataTable style="width: 700px;" var="coun" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.countryList}" selection="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deletingObj}" rowKey="#{coun.countryId}"
                                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                             paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25" editable="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this"
                                            listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.onEditRow}" />

                                    <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete the selected row ?"
                                                     header="Deleting Row" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation2">
                                        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update=":mainForm" oncomplete="confirmation2.hide()"
                                                         action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deleteObject}" />
                                        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation2.hide()" type="button" />
                                    </p:confirmDialog>


                                    <p:column headerText="Country">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{coun.country}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <p:inputText value="#{coun.country}" style="width:100%" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column id="inactive" filterBy="#{coun.isActive}"   
                                              headerText="isActive" footerText="exact" 
                                              filterOptions="#{profileInfoManagedBean.isActiveDropDown}"
                                              filterMatchMode="exact">

                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{coun.isActive}"></h:outputText>
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{coun.isActive}" >  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" /> 
                                                </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Edit">
                                        <p:rowEditor />

                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Delete">
                                        <p:commandButton update=":mainForm:growl :mainForm:myTabViewID:aPanel:countryTable" icon="ui-icon-circle-close" action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deleteCountry(coun.countryId)}" 
                                                         title="Delete Country" style="border-color:#FF0000" />
                                    </p:column>


                                </p:dataTable>
                            </p:outputPanel>

                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="tab2" title="Province">

                            <p:outputPanel>  
                                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.province.country.countryId}" id="cou"
                                                         required="false">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Here" itemValue="" />
                                            <f:selectItems
                                                value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.countryList}"
                                                var="coun" itemValue="#{coun.countryId}" itemLabel="#{coun.country}" />
                                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg2" />
                                        </p:selectOneMenu><p:message id="msg2" for="cou" display="icon" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:outputLabel for="province"  value="Province: "></h:outputLabel>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:inputText id="province" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.province.province}" required="false" label="Province">
                                            <p:watermark value="Enter a province name" for="province" />
                                            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20" />
                                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg3"></p:ajax>
                                        </p:inputText>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:message id="msg3" for="province" display="icon"></p:message>
                                    </p:column>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                                <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{profileInfoManagedBean.addProvince}" update=":mainForm" style="margin:10px 0" id="btnAddProvince"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>

                            <p:separator />
                            <p:outputPanel id="provinceTable">

                                <p:dataTable style="width: 700px;" var="prov" value="#{profileInfoManagedBean.provinceList}" selection="#{profileInfoManagedBean.deletingObj}" rowKey="#{prov.provinceId}"
                                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                             paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20,25" editable="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this"
                                            listener="#{profileInfoManagedBean.onEditRow}" />


                                    <p:column headerText="Province">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{prov.province}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <p:inputText value="#{prov.province}" style="width:100%" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column id="inactive" filterBy="#{coun.isActive}"   
                                              headerText="isActive" footerText="exact" 
                                              filterOptions="#{profileInfoManagedBean.isActiveDropDown}"
                                              filterMatchMode="exact">

                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{prov.isActive}"></h:outputText>
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{prov.isActive}" >  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="true" />  
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="false" /> 
                                                </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Edit">
                                        <p:rowEditor />
                                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-close" onclick="deleteObj(5)" title="Delete Province" style="border-color:#FF0000" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Delete">

                                        <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="confirmation1.show()" 
                                                         id="delProvince" title="Delete Province" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column selectionMode="single">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="select" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                    </p:column>


                                </p:dataTable>
                            </p:outputPanel>

                        </p:tab>

                    </p:accordionPanel>

                </p:tab>


                <p:tab id="basicInfoTab" title="Basic info">
                    <p:accordionPanel id="aPanel1">
                        <p:tab id="tab2" title="basic   info">
                            This is basic info tab.
                            This is basic info tab.
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:accordionPanel>
                </p:tab>



            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I've many tabview and accordion tabs. `activeindex` worked when I made `required="false"` for every component of one tab. Changing all to `required="true"` caused `activeindex` not to work, but if you change to `required="false"` of components of only one tab `activeindex` works just fine.

Comment: What exactly is the problem being faced is not clear. Can you please give details. Also, it will be useful if the source of the bean is posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `<p:tabView` is in a `<h:form`, _activeIndex is updated.
If `<p:tabView` is NOT in a `<h:form`, _activeIndex is NOT updated.
This can be seen in the POST using Firebug.

From what I can tell, _activeIndex and _activetab should have same value with TabView component.

I use the following code with multiple tabs, and different form in each tab:

```
public void tabIsChanged(TabChangeEvent event) {
  //This code was taken directly from TabViewRenderer.
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getComponent();
  String activeIndexValue = params.get(tabView.getClientId(context) + "_tabindex");

  //this.activeTab = Integer.parseInt(activeIndexValue);
  this.myCurrentATab = Integer.parseInt(activeIndexValue);

}
```

Maybe this a solution for you.

Comment: I am using: Prime Faces 3.2, Mojarra 2.1.7, Apache Tomcat 7.0.26

Comment: was searching for this for a couple of days now. works like charm with PF 4-SNAPSHOT and Mojarra 2.19 on JBoss 7.1.1

Comment: Also good to know that you still need a setter even if its not updated / not in form in case you have a form inside any tab and invoke an ajax request. This will still trigger the set operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the active tab, this is one way:

---

```
<p:tabView>

    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"/>

    <p:tab title="TitleTabOne"></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="TitleTabTwo"></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="TitleTabThree"></p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

---

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getComponent();
    int activeTabIndex = tabView.getActiveIndex();
    System.out.println(activeTabIndex);
    if(activeTabIndex == 1){                    
        // Your tab is active, do something...
    }
}
```

---

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `tabView` with `activeIndex` and add that code inside of `tabView` will solve like:

```
        <p:tabView id="tv" activeIndex="#{yourBean.activeTabIndex}">

            <p:ajax event="tabChange" process="@this"/>

        </p:tabView>
```

Without `tabChangeEvent` `activeIndex` will not work.